# How to import mutiple modules from webpack?

Tags: javascript, performance, reactjs, webpack

I've around 20 `jsx` files with the few repeated `imports` like :

```
import React from 'react';
import { Form } from 'formsy-react';
import AppActions from '../../utils/actions/app-actions';
import store, {formStore} from '../../utils/stores/stores';
import AppConstants from '../../utils/constants/app-constants';
```

which cause my bundle.js weight more than 1.7 Mb even after minification.
Is there any possiblity to import these modules from any where else so that I don't need to import these again and again.

Comment: Webpack inserts each required module only once into the bundle (except for some edge cases), even if it's referenced 20 times. So that's not what is causing your bundle to be big. You usually don't care about size in development, but in production you should do all the minimizing steps like uglify and compress. Also you can [split the bundle to multiple pieces](https://webpack.github.io/docs/code-splitting.html).

Comment: In production you can use the DedupePlugin to ensure each file is included only once, if duplicated files are indeed your issue. The repeated imports won't cause duplicated files though - Webpack will still include each module once.  1.7MB does seem pretty big for a minified bundle.

Comment: Try this tool and investigate size of your modules https://chrisbateman.github.io/webpack-visualizer/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is a misunderstanding here between Webpack, ES6 and a module.

Webpack is going to analyse your javascript code and detect the dependencies, based on that it will include the modules you need in your bundle, there is no duplicate there, every module is added only once in the proper order to resolve the dependencies while avoiding duplicates of code.

ES6 import export syntax convention requires to define the imports you need in every file that requires them, so browsers or tools like Webpack can properly detect dependencies and only use files they need.

1.7 Mb can be considered as a big file for a web page, but with a proper caching/minification it can be loaded instantly

Comment: 1.7 Mb is after all minification process. Is it because the level of code I'm writing..? please suggest.

Comment: 1.7 Mb for a Reactjs project is not that bad, if you have react-router, redux, etc, it can be pretty big pretty easily, nothing wrong with that